# What do the arguments to CSS3's animation-timing-function cubic-bezier() mean?

Tags: css, math, css-transitions, css-animations

You pass `cubic-bezier` four different real number values, it creates a bezier curve.

For instance, `cubic-bezier(0,0,1,1)` creates a `linear` curve. `cubic-bezier(0.25,0.1,0.25,1)` creates an `ease` curve.

But [a cubic bezier curve is defined by four points on a plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B.C3.A9zier_curves), and we only have four real values, which would only describe two points.

So what do these numbers mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function):

> A cubic Bézier curve is defined by four points P0, P1, P2, and P3. P0 and P3 are the start and the end of the curve and, in CSS these points are fixed as the coordinates are ratios (the abscissa the ratio of time, the ordinate the ratio of the output range). P0 is (0, 0) and represents the initial time and the initial state, P3 is (1, 1) and represents the final time and the final state.

So the start and end points are automatically fixed at (0, 0) and (1, 1) - you are actually setting the inner two points (P1 and P2).

Comment: Thanks--so clarifying!